# How to stop for loop once it has been looped to all records in a list

Tags: java, android

I am using for loop in my program, and i want to know how can i stop this once it has been looped to all records in a list one by one.

```
btnSyncAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i=0; i<ImageList.size(); i++)
            {
                new SyncFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(i));                                                            
            }   
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is what forloop does. It traverses the complete record count once. If you are stuck in an infinite loop, you may want to debug and check the size of imagelist.

Comment: Loop will be completed by itself after the last element in ImageList, as async tasks will be executed in background. What's the issue?

Comment: wow, you make async every byte of the picture? just wow....

Comment: @madLokesh have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160822/how-sync-all-records-available-in-a-list

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira why you kidding ? have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160822/how-sync-all-records-available-in-a-list

Comment: ops, sorry. i read it wrong. i think image file, not list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a for loop is that it stops after it looped from `int i = 0` to `i < imageList.size()`. I dont know why you have the feeling that it doesnt, but probably your `imageList` is really big and it takes a lot of time until the loop is finished.

Comment: have a look at this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160822/how-sync-all-records-available-in-a-list

Comment: still i am facing this issue, whereas i have only 8 records in a list but its taking huge time even i have to cancel it... what could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

For loop stops iterating when it reaches the limit you defined in for loop statement. But if you want to stop in middle you have to put break with certain condition check.

i.e.

for(int i=0;i < n;i++){

```
   if(i==4){
          break;
   }
```

}

if you want to not to execute for particular iteration use continue statement.